# I get the error "Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response" despite following proper response format

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get a random number from an AWS Lambda via a POST request. I have extra challenge here by being new to lambdas and serverless. I am still learning all the ins and outs of the AWS UI.

This all started yesterday when `curl https://ix14jbto25.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users/random` responded with `{"message": "Internal server error"}`. I tried changing the method from GET to POST in the `serverless.yml` file, thinking maybe the issue was me trying to send a body back with a GET request. That wasn't it.

I also tried various combinations of async/not async, returning an object or using the callback.

Later, someone told me to look in the API Gateway UI for a Test feature. I used the Test and found this additional clue:

```
Tue Oct 17 15:53:56 UTC 2023 : Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Tue Oct 17 15:53:56 UTC 2023 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Tue Oct 17 15:53:56 UTC 2023 : Method completed with status: 502
```

A [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111754/aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-response-integration-issue) of [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004997/malformed-lambda-proxy-response-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-nodejs) posts [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816537/aws-lambda-api-gateway-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response-status-error-502) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697024/execution-failed-due-to-configuration-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response-whi) [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078401/aws-api-gateway-execution-failed-due-to-configuration-error-malformed-lambda) discuss the solution being in the format of the return value or callback. But mine is formatted correctly:

```
export const getRandomNum = (event, context) => {
  try {
    const number = Math.random() * 100;
    console.log(number, "199");
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { headers },
      isBase64Encoded: false,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "look, a cat" }),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: { headers },
      isBase64Encoded: false,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "look, a dog" }),
    };
  }
};
```

Unless, perhaps, I am making an error without realizing it?

I can confirm via CloudWatch logs that the return statements / callback execution is reached by putting console logs just before them.

Some relevant portions of my `serverless.yml`

```
service: pluto-lama-users-service

frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x

functions:
  getRandomNum:
    handler: entrypoint.getRandomNum
    events:
      - http:
          path: /users/random
          method: post
```

edit: The solution ended up being that I need *both* of (a) a specific shape in the response, namely `{statusCode: someStatusCode, headers, isBase64Encoded: true|false, body}` *and* (b) to either use `async` + `return {}` or non-async + `callback(null, {})`

It is now solved!